# special pointer value ((void*)1)

Tags: pointers, gcc

I am trying to use a special pointer with a guaranteed invalid address with gcc. Here is what I do:

```
#define MY_VALUE_OK ((void*)1);
...
int*            data;
...
void* d = MY_VALUE_OK;

if( data != ((void*)1) )        // compiles ok

if( data != d )                 // compiles ok

if( data != MY_VALUE_OK )       // error!

    printf( " %d", *data );
```

Any ideas?
Ideally I'd like to define this pointer as static const in a class.
BTW, this is my old code that used to compile with Microsoft Visual Studio just fine.

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Answer (score 3):

Does your #define include a semi-colon (like your example does)? If so that would allow the assignment to work, but the if statement would error out because after the text substitution, there would be a semi-colon inside the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined a semicolon with your #define

so...

```
if(data != MY_VALUE_OK)
```

Actually turns into:

```
if(data != ((void*)1);)
```

There is an obvious error there

Your define should be:

```
#define MY_VALUE_OK ((void*)1)
```

That should fix your problem :)